# index and access JSON multi dimension array objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to solve two problem from the code below.

```
var employees = [
    {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName :"Doe",
      qualification: {Diploma: 'IT Software' , Degree: 'Software Engineering'}
    }, 
    {
    firstName:"Anna",
    lastName:"Smith",
      qualification: {Diploma: 'Business Accountant' , Degree: 'Business Administration'}
    }
];

for(var i in employees)
  {
    console.log(employees[i]);

  }
```

The output from the code above is as follow.

```
[object Object] {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  qualification: [object Object] {
    Degree: "Software Engineering",
    Diploma: "IT Software"
  }
}
[object Object] {
  firstName: "Anna",
  lastName: "Smith",
  qualification: [object Object] {
    Degree: "Business Administration",
    Diploma: "Business Accountant"
  }
}
```

I am looking to index the output that is instead of [object object] it should display [index: 1] and [index : 2] for the respective object.

Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That's not JSON. That's a JavaScript array initializer containing JavaScript object initializers. If you're in JavaScript source code, you're not dealing with JSON (unless it's in a string).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `for-in` (without safeguards) to loop through arrays ([details and alternatives listed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)), that's not what it's for.

If you want both the object and its index in the array, your best bet is is `forEach`:

```
employees.forEach(function(employee, i) {
    console.log("[index: " + (i + 1) + "]");
    // And if you need the actual employee object,
    // it's `employee`
});
```

Note the `i + 1`: Indexes in JavaScript (and programming in general) usually start with `0`, not `1`, so to get your desired output, we add one to the index.

Alternately, a boring old `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < employees.length; ++i)
{
    console.log("[index: " + (i + 1) + "]");
    // And if you need the actual employee object, as
    // with your code, it's `employees[i]`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are looping the array in the for bucle you get the index with the variable *i*

```
for(var i in employees)
    console.log("index:"+ i);
```